# TCP communication on Vista

Tags: wcf, iis-7, windows-vista, tcp

I have a very simple app I'm trying to get to run under TCP using WCF 3.5 on Vista Enterpise. The error I'm getting when trying to hit a WCF service at http://localhost:8080 (or any other port not reserved by http) is:

TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8080.

I've gotten this to work a few months ago, but I forgot how. I'm wondering if I have the port reserved or something...I've tried allowing the compiled executable through Windows Firewall and tried opening port 8080 for TCP through the firewall, but i get the same error. Any thoughts or ideas on where to look or what to check?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try going to http://*machinename*:8080 - I've had Vista make firewall distinctions based on that before, especially if the Loopback adapter was installed

Comment: Any reason why http would allow localhost and tcp would not? This just bugs me b/c I know I've gotten this to work before on this laptop.

Comment: HTTP and TCP work on different layers of the stack - HTTP *uses* TCP.  The difference here is the contents of the packets.  The question you need to ask yourself, is why does it not work on anything but port 80?

Answer (score 0):

No dice. Changing localhost to the machine name doesn't let me in.

It's not http that is having the problem...localhost works fine there as well. But everything I've tried to do with tcp has faild with the same error. Completely frustrating as I know I've seen this work on this box before.

**Edit to include commented answer:** *Just FYI, finally found the problem. Something was misnamed in the service's config file. I wish the error could have been a bit clearer, but all is well. Thanks!*

Comment: Just FYI, finally found the problem. Something was misnamed in the service's config file. I wish the error could have been a bit clearer, but all is well. Thanks!